# Find the fixed field of $f\colon K(X)\to K(X)$ given by $f(X)=1/X$

Tags: field-theory

Let $K(X)$ denote the field of fractions of the polynomial ring $K[X]$ over a field $K$.

Find the fixed field of the automorphism $f\colon K(X)\to K(X)$ given by $f(X)=1/X$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You should always share your thoughts on a problem and explain where you are stuck. Please edit your question to reflect this. Also please revise your title, it is quite incomprehensible.

Comment: @christoph Pegel i try but i do not know how to really ask question herer.

Comment: I edited your question, please verify it still reflects what you want to ask.

Comment: @christoph yes it is perfect what i want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

$r(X)\in K(X)$ is in the fixed field iff:
$$
r(X)=f(r(X))=r(f(X))=r(1/X).
$$
A sufficient condition for this is $r(X)=p(X)/q(X)$ with $p(X),q(X)\in P[X]$ of the same degree s.t. $P(X)=a_nX^n+\cdots a_1X+a_0$ with $a_{k}=a_{n-k}$, $k=0,\cdots,n$ and the same condition for $q(X)$. Check yourself if it is necessary.

Comment: thank you I try it in this way.

Comment: (x^2+1)/x is fixed under given automorphism but here the degree of p,q is not same. Also notice that q does not satisfied the 2nd condition.